# Screen/Desktop sharing in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

What are some of the ways in which we can do desktop/screen sharing using Flash?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Adobe LiveCycle Collaboration Service, which comes with a cross-platform software called "Adobe ConnectNow", which allows you to share a window, all windows of an application or the entire screen with other users, out of the browser.

The SDK contains widgets for Webcam Sharing, Audio Sharing and Screen Sharing as well as a Text Chat, Shared data models, etc., which you can easily combine into a Flex or pure Flash Application. Have a look at the video tutorial below.

- [Adobe LCCS](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/services/collaboration.html)
- [Video tutorial on creating a full-fledged collaboration app (webcam, audio, text chat, screen sharing) in 10 minutes](http://www.riagora.com/2010/09/build-a-chat-with-flex-test/)

Answer (score 1):

I can hardly see it being possible without using AIR (and even with AIR) seeing how Flash has its access basically just limited to its own environment.